# Multi functional table

Tags: data-tables

I need your valuable feedback about a data-table I am trying to RE-design for a complex admin page.

To sum up;

- There are "user roles" created on a page admin system.
- There are also "users" registered on the same system.
- The goal is the link a group of user to any chosen role. You can add
  roles to the table and add users to the roles.

Use case : As an administrator of my company, I would like to select available approval roles from a list to display them on a table and assign users to the selected roles. I would like to easily modify the role list and delete/add users assigned to them.

This is the current table to redesign
[image: This is the current table to redesign]

This is the table UI - V1
[image: This is what I did so far]

This is the table UI - V2
[image]

This is the curent UI when the user clicks and add/remove roles
[image: This is the curent UI when the user clicks and add/remove roles]

This is the format we are going to use for add/remove roles UI (above), except with filters, search bar and expendable sections for each role categorie, so the user wont have to scroll forever..

[image]

The feedback I am looking for :

1- Is the add / remove functionality clear enough ?

2- Instead of the "add roles button", should I put "edit roles" or "add/remove roles"?

3- Is "add/remove users" (edit users) clear enough ? When I click on "edit", I will have user list on a pop-in with also a search bar.

Note : (inherited from toto) means "Same as parent" but as there is alot of parent companies we dont know which one, thats why I display the name of the parent company which is toto in this case.

Thanks alot for your time, shoot if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

1- I didn't see the buttons to add a role and remove a role immediately, and I had to look for them to finally see them. (The high contrast of the orange links in the old interface was making these pop out more)
I would place them above the table, where they would be more obvious, especially if the table is long. I would rename "Remove role" to "Remove selected role(s)" to make sure the user understand that they need to select a role to enable the remove button. 
In the table itself, I would change Name to Role Name. For a while, I was thinking that each row was a combination of multiple roles.

2- The add role interface is more complicated than necessary because it does 2 things at once: add roles and remove them. It duplicates information that already exists in the table, and the remove role functionality. 
As it's now possible to remove selected roles with a dedicated button, I would limit the add role interface to something similar to what you describe for users: with a list of available roles to add, the possibility to select them and add them to the table.

3- Add/remove users is more explicit than simply edit.

Comment: thanks for the valuable feedback.
1-You are right on Remove role vs Remove selected role(s). I also renamed Name to Role Name.
2-We changed our approch for editing roles, you can see the structure we are currently considering on my post that I edited.
3-Add/remove users is more explicite you are right but it takes too much space so I am thinking to put "add user(s)" when there is 0 users and edit users when there are some users. 
Thanks again !